# How do I fix the For Loop to return a certain character from a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have imported an excel file and made it into a DataFrame and iterated over a column called "Titles" to spit out titles with certain keywords. I have the list of titles as "match_titles." What I want to do now is to create a For Loop to return the column before "titles" for each title in match_titles." I'm not sure why the code is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\bryanmccormack\Downloads\asin_list.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Track','Asin','Title'])

excludes = ["Chainsaw", "Diaper pail", "Leaf Blower"]
my_excludes = [set(key_word.lower().split()) for key_word in excludes]
match_titles = [e for e in df.Title if 
any(keywords.issubset(e.lower().split()) for keywords in my_excludes)]

a = []
for i in match_titles:
    a.append(df['Asin'])
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop you are appending the unfiltered column `df['Asin']` to your list `a` as many times as there are values in `match_titles`.  But there isn't any filtering of `df`.

One solution would be to make a column of the `match_values` then you can return the column `Asin` after filtering on that `match_values` column:

```
# make a function to perform your match analysis.
def is_match(title, excludes=["Chainsaw", "Diaper pail", "Leaf Blower"]):
    my_excludes = [set(key_word.lower().split()) for key_word in excludes]
    if any(keywords.issubset(title.lower().split()) for keywords in my_excludes):
        return True
    return False

# Make a new boolean column for the matches.  This applies your
# function to each value in df['Title'] and puts the output in
# the new column.
df['match_titles'] = df['Title'].apply(is_match)

# Filter the df to only matches and return the column you want.
# Because the match_titles column is boolean it can be used as
# an index.
result = df[df['match_titles']]['Asin']
```